# System.IO.IOException: 'The parameter is incorrect.' when NamedPipeClientStreamReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message

Tags: c#, .net, ipc

I am trying to create a NamedPipeClientStream and I can't set the ReadMode to Message

```cs
            Stream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", GetPathFromID(id), PipeDirection.InOut);

            Console.WriteLine("Tried to connect: " + id);

            try
            {
                Stream.Connect(100);

                if (Stream.IsConnected)
                {
                    Stream.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;
                    new Thread(StartReading).Start();
                }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Faied to connect: " + id);
            }
```

Comment: [PipeStream.ReadMode Property Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.pipestream.readmode?#exceptions)

Comment: Why would it be broken tho

Comment: Did you solve this?